# How to add asm library to java project?

Tags: java

I have simple question but I couldn't find an answer ;/
How can I create and call assembler library inside java project? 
I have found something like this to call created library:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("start");

            System.loadLibrary("native");
            (new Hello()).nativeCode();

            System.out.println("stop");
    }

    public native void nativeCode();
```

}

but solution to create library is based on linux so I cant figure out how to do it on win 7 64 bit.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks from advice.

Comment: Build a DLL in assembly with JNI-comliant functions that conform to the cdecl calling convention. Visual Studio can help you here, once you enable the "masm" customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling native code from Java is accomplished using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).  You'll need to write a Java class that includes method(s) declared using the `native` keyword, and in your native library you'll need to include a corresponding function with the appropriate name and parameters for the JVM to call.

Since the native function called by the JVM takes arguments whose types are defined in the C header `jni.h`, and you interact with the JVM by calling C functions declared in that same header, you'll probably find it easiest to write some C (or C++) code of your own to act as an intermediary between the JVM and your assembler code.

The details of how to actually build the native library are platform-specific, but not Java-specific; on Windows, Java's `System.loadLibrary()` just loads ordinary DLL files.  Your compiler/assembler documentation should provide information on how to build one.

Comment: What about [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)? Would not it be better? I don't have any experience of them, I am just curious...

Comment: @Katona, I haven't used JNA, nor even heard of it before now.  It looks like it does some mapping of Java types to native types, which would help with calling native functions that weren't specifically written to be called from Java.  That comes at the cost of efficiency, though:  for example, passing a string to a native function probably involves copying it to the native heap and converting it in the process to a C-style string, rather than the native code calling JNI functions to directly access the character data on the Java heap.